# Accessing values stored in object c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a new instance of my object then storing each instance of a virtual function into an array.

The problem is that I cannot get the value of each object once I create it,

To be clear I just want each instance of `floors` I create to return the value int when called. As my virtual function `build(int a)` returns a `int`

current output is

```
We are adding a spot to value 0 in our array
```

I need the value to also be added to this `output`

So based on my current example it should show the value 5

I assume this should work because of `myBuilding.add(new floors(5));`

complex.h

```
class complex {

protected:
    int num;

public:
    virtual void build(int a) {
        num = a;
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
 #include "floors.h"

    int main() {

        building myBuilding;

        myBuilding.add(new floors(5));

        myBuilding.build();

        return 0;
    }
```

floors.h

```
class floors : public complex {
private:
    int quantity;

public:
    floors(const int& init_quant) :
    quantity(init_quant)
    {
    }

    int build(floors()) {
        std::cout << "This is the floors class" << quantity << '\n';
        return quantity;
    }
};
```

And this is the class handling the array,
building.h

```
class building {
public:
    static const int max_materials = 100;
    complex* materials[max_materials];
    int num_materials;

public:
    building() : num_materials(0) {}

    ~building() {
        for(int i = 0; i < num_materials; ++i) { delete materials[i]; }
    }

    bool add(complex* s) {
        if(num_materials >= max_materials) { return false; }
        materials[num_materials++] = s;
        return true;
    }

    void build() {
        for(int i = 0; i < num_materials; ++i) { materials[i]->build(i);
            std::cout << "We are adding a spot to value " << i << " in our array" <<  '\n';

        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Just a side note on your code.  You will have a memory leak every time you try to add a floor and you have gone beyond `max_materials`.  It would be better to use a `std::array` and store `std::unique_ptr`, than you won't have to worry about the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the input bro. Ya I am very new to c++ and love it to death man! This assignment was a lot simpler then this. And there is a lot more to it then i showed cause I am play with it now thats it done cause I want to learn more. I like to learn to do everything possible with each assignment so I really no my stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, my C++ is becoming rusty as it has been almost 2 years since I was programming in it professionally.  I am going to answer as no one else has, but there is probably a better/more correct answer that could be given.

1. You are getting the output you are seeing because of this line:

   ```
   std::cout << "We are adding a spot to value " << i << " in our array" <<  '\n';
   ```

   That line is saying to print out the value of `i`, not the value that is contained within the floor object when you call `build`.
2. You are calling `build(0)` in the first iteration of that loop.  This is going to call the `build` function in the base class `complex` class that has a return type of `void`.  Since `floors` is a child of `complex` and the method signature for the method `build` that best matches is the one that takes an int and returns void.  So in your example, you have created a `floors` object with a `quantity` of 5 but then when you call the `build` method, you are actually calling the base class `build` which sets `num` to a value of 0.  You will not be able to access the `num` value from the `building` class due to it being marked as `protected`.
3. As I am a bit rusty and I haven't experimented with it, I can't tell you what the signature of the `build` method in the `floors` class actually is, but I can guarantee you that it isn't what you think it is.  I am confused as to what you actually want it to be.  Do you really want it to take a different `floor` object.  The way it is being used I would expect this is the signature you are looking for.

   ```
   int build() {
       std::cout << "This is the floors class" << quantity << '\n';
       return quantity;
   }
   ```

In order to get the output that I think you are looking for you will need to change the `build` method in the `building` class to look something like this (Note, you also have to change the build method in the floor class to match the method I have listed in point 3):

```
void build() {
    for(int i = 0; i < num_materials; ++i) {
        int quantity = materials[i]->build();
        std::cout << "We are adding a spot to value " << quantity << " in our array" <<  '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that. It doesn't return quantity for some reason.

Comment: @NDiaz When you say you tried it, do you mean you tried making that signature. That won't solve your problem.  If you look at point 2 in my list you will see that the function that is being called in the `building::build` call is not the `build` in the `floor` class, but rather the `build` in the `complex` class.  I have updated my answer to show how to change the build method in the building class.

Comment: @NDiaz - I have added a couple of updates to my answer.  It was not exactly clear from your question what you were after so I hope I have answered appropriately.